# Verify if a Column of a particular SQL Table is present or not from a given Select SQL Query(Oracle) , using Python and no access to Database

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sql-parser, sqlglot

Given a SQL query(Oracle) I want to find if column of a particular table is present in it or not.
I want to achieve this using Python.
I do not have any access to the Database and I needed this for analysis purpose.

I have thought about using Regular expressions but I think it might cause errors and there is a possibility of giving wrong results from complex SQL queries

so I have tried using sqlglot(sqlparser) library and was able to extract columns and table names separately. But I wanted to find columns as in Table_name.Columns and should be able to find even though the table name or column name get **aliased**.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: How would you know if some column is present in some table with no database access? It's impossible

Comment: You will have to give an example of what you're trying to do. It sounds like you might be wanting to parse the text of a SQL statement and mine the source objects it reads? That will not be an easy task without actually using the database and letting it parse it for you. And it would also be of very limited value. How would you handle `*`? Or if the "tables" it uses are actually views or synonyms? I think you need to get access to the database, parse the SQL and then use the plan to get the object listing and column projection. Or consider whether what you're trying to do needs doing at all.

Comment: so the SQL Query will always be select query so is it still possible to find the table.column in this case

Comment: Well, in a query like `select x from y` or `select z.x from y z` then you know that table `Y` has a column named `X`. However, constructions like `select a.b from (select x as b from y) a` will make it increasingly hard to tell which column comes from which table, in self-written Python code. If you are looking for suggestions for a ready-made library then that is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not possible without access to the database.

It is perfectly legal to write SQL statements where some columns don't have aliases

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM parent p
       join child c on (c.parent_id = p.parent_id)
 WHERE p.parent_id = 12345;
```

Without access to the database, it is impossible to determine whether `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are coming from the `parent` table or the `child` table (or both in which case a syntax error would be thrown).

You get similar issues when you have something like

```
SELECT a.b( 123 )
```

Where `a` could be a schema name and `b` a function in that schema or `a` could be a package name and `b` a function within that package (and this only gets more complicated if you're taking advantage of your database and using object types and things like that that create more possible interpretations).